# What kind of standard deviation must be used in optimization algorithms?

Tags: optimization, heuristics, genetic-algorithms, statistics

I would like to ask about the standard deviation of objective function value.

There are two types of standard deviations:

1. Population standard deviation
2. Sample standard deviation

In metaheuristic optimization algorithms most scholars are used std in your papers. What kind of standard deviation is used in metaheuristic optimization algorithms?

Comment: The difference is usually very slight.

Comment: Different subfields have different conventions. For instance, in the value oracle model, there isn't such a distinction (that I've encountered). To better address your question, do you mind putting a link to where you are seeing this used?